# Alternative of CyanogenMod-5 but Android 2.1 for HTC Dream G1

Tags: cyanogenmod, 2.1-eclair, htc-dream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

I am currently using Cyanogenmod-5 (Android 2.1) for my HTC Dream G1. But it runs quite slow and I dont want to go back to Android 1.x series.

I am looking for some other Android 2.1 OS (other than Cyanogenmod) which are faster and have low memory requirements or does it remain the same among all Android 2.1 distributions?

Another reason for change is that every 1 or 2 months, Cyanogenmod-5 starts behaving funny and I need to re-install my OS. For example, currently I am unable to read any texts (Messaging service - SMS) on my phone; application keeps on crashing. In the past similar issues were with Gmail and GTalk.

So, I want to switch to something other than Cyanogenmod but Android-2.1. Any suggestions?

Comment: This seems like it's essentially a "shopping recommendation" style of question (albeit without monetary exchange taking place). How will you assess an answer as correct/incorrect? What prevents this from becoming a potentially unending list? See ["Where can I find X ROM" questions should be treated like shopping questions](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/782) for the meta discussion about these types of questions and the linked duplicate for resources/lists that may help you.

Comment: I was looking for some suggestions of different ROMs that I can use for my HTC Dream G1.